# EF 4.3 Multiple Enumeration Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

We are using EF 4.3 for our data layer and have a generic repository pattern in place. Backend is SQL 2008 R2 and the project is .NET 4.0/MVC 3 but I don't think that this factors into the question.

Basically, we have a one to many relationship in our database of two objects.  One is for 'Traps' and the second is for 'Trap Activities'.  Meaning, once one of these 'Traps' is deployed, anything that happens to that trap is kept in the Trap Activity table.  Should be a fairly straightforward way of doing this.

The relationship is defined with a FK in the 'Trap Activity' table to the PK of the 'Traps' table.  Both tables have PKs defined.

In our service layer, I need to query out a list of 'Traps' with the date that these traps were deployed.  This is accomplished by the following code snippet:

```
var traps = this.trapRepository.Find(x => x.DeploymentYear == 2012).Select(x => new TrapHomeViewModel
            {
                County = x.County.Name,
                DeploymentDate = x.TrapActivities.First(y => y.ActivityType == 1).ActivityDate,
                State = x.County.CountyState.Abbreviation,
                Latitude = x.Latitude,
                Longitude = x.Longitude,
                TrapId = x.TrapID,
                TrapNumber = x.SerialNumber,
                Centroid = x.TrapCentroid
            }).ToList();
```

The issue is around the DeploymentDate property.  As written, this takes 25s to return a list of around 3000 items.  Updating the Trap table to have the deployment date to be stored there and populating with this line:

```
DeploymentDate = x.DeploymentDate.Value.Date
```

Results in a less than 1s response time.  Now I think I know what is going on here (multiple enumerations of the data set) but what I thought would happen would be a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT     Counties.Name, TrapActivities.ActivityDate, States.Abbreviation, 
Traps.Latitude, Traps.Longitude, Traps.TrapID, Traps.SerialNumber, Traps.TrapCentroid
    FROM         TrapActivities INNER JOIN
                          Traps ON TrapActivities.TrapID = Traps.TrapID INNER JOIN
                          Counties ON Traps.CountyID = Counties.CountyID INNER JOIN
                          States ON Counties.State = States.FIPS_Code
    WHERE     (TrapActivities.ActivityType = 1)
```

...but that does not seem to be the case.  With all the background information above, where have I strayed in populating this view model?  I don't think I have ran into this issue before but this is also a much larger dataset than some of our other projects.  Any guidance on this would be much helpful.  If I need to provide any other information, please let me know.

**EDIT**

As requested, the GenericRepository Find method and constructors:

```
 public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
        where T : class
    {
        private readonly IObjectSet<T> objectSet;
        private ObjectContext context;

        public GenericRepository()
            : this(new APHISEntities())
        {
        }

        public GenericRepository(ObjectContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.objectSet = this.context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        }    

        public IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            return this.objectSet.Where(predicate);
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

This is an example of the SQL being generated by the above code:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[TrapActivityID] AS [TrapActivityID], 
[Extent1].[TrapID] AS [TrapID], 
[Extent1].[ActivityType] AS [ActivityType], 
[Extent1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
[Extent1].[AgentID] AS [AgentID], 
[Extent1].[ActivityDate] AS [ActivityDate], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Extent1].[EditedOn] AS [EditedOn], 
[Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Extent1].[VisualInspectionID] AS [VisualInspectionID]
FROM [dbo].[TrapActivities] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[TrapID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 uniqueidentifier',@EntityKeyValue1='FEBC7ED4-E726-4F5E-B2BA-FFD53AB7DF34'
```

It looks to me that it is taking a list of Trap Ids and then running a query for each one, resulting in thousands of SQL statements being generated.  It also appears to be running individual queries for the County information as well.

Comment: Best bet in this situation and for future situations is to run a profiler such as Anjlab sql profiler on your database. It'll show you the exact SQL that is executing and how long each call takes. You'll then be able to see if it's doing anything super inefficiently. You probably just need to add some indexes to your database to speed it up. Once you find the query that's taking 25 seconds, SSMS has an option to view the execution path, and you should see where the problems lie.

Comment: You can see exactly what query is being generated by grabbing the network traffic (Wire Shark will do this) and looking at it, then see if you have the indexes to optimize it.  You might be surprised by the query it generates - I was with some of mine.

Comment: What does your repository's `Find` method look like?

Comment: After the SQL profiler - it looks like what I suspected.  EF is generating thousands of queries.  It looks like EF gets a list of traps, then queries the Trap table and the Trap Activity table for each TrapId from the .Find() statement.  Example in Edit #2

Comment: I've added a suggested fix to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your repository, you can use `ObjectQuery.ToTraceString` to see what SQL is getting executed before you return your objects.

You are returning all of the actual `Trap` objects deployed in 2012 from your repository find method, instead of an IQueryable AND you are not eager loading `TrapActivities`. That means as you enumerate through the results in `Select` to create your view model, you are sending a new query to the DB for each `Trap` to get it's `TrapActivities`.

**Update 1**

I think you will need to implement a specific query in your repository for this.

```
var q = from t in traps 
        where t.DeploymentYear == 2012
        select new TrapFirstDeployment {
            Trap = t,
            DeploymentActivity = t.TrapActivities.Where(ta=>ta.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.ActivityType=1))
        };

return q.Where(tfd=>tfd.DeploymentActivity != null);
```

**Explanation**

The reason your initial query was slow is because EF doesn't eager load child relationships unless you tell it to. Lazy Loading is on by default. Since you don't tell it to load `TrapActivities` with your `Trap` in your repository, it waits until you access it the first time to load them. This is great you need the trap but not the activities because it reduces traffic to/from the DB. However, in some situations you need them. In that case you can force an eager load by adding `Include` in your query. e.g.,

```
var q = from t in this.objectSet.Include('TrapActivities')
        select t;
```

This loads ALL of the `TrapActivities` with the trap in one query. However, in your case, you only need the first deployment activity which is why I created the `TrapFirstDeployment` class. This way, EF should only grab the first deployment activity.

**Update 2**

You should also change the parameter on the `Find` method on your repository to `Expression<Func<T,Boolean>>` to match the `IQueryable.Where` signature. `IEnumerable.Where` uses `Func<T,Boolean>` so that is why `objectSet` is getting converted to an `IEnumberable` before `Where` is called.

Comment: That's what it appears like to me as well - can you recommend a fix to  what I have above to get rid of this?  Is it an .edmx change or a repository implementation change?

Comment: Ok - I will give this a go and see what the result is.  I am still stumped as to why it is doing the multiple enumerations of the dataset though

Comment: Wouldn't have noticed if I hadn't been bitten by that exact same bug myself several months ago. :)

Comment: Thanks Brian, that seemed to fix the issue.  My generic repository was a little 'too generic' and in this instance, it makes more sense to query exactly what I need up front.  Sorry for the delay, it took a little bit to get this implemented and then vacation...

Answer (score 1):

As @SLC said: you need to look at the SQL that EF is generating - you'll be amazed.

I recommend using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). There are free and paid versions.

The thing I like the most is you can import your Data Layer assembly and write LINQ statements against your model. It makes it easy to test different query approaches.

---

The fix could be as easy as returning `IQueryable` from `Find` instead of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to change the .Find() method but it appears that the method signature for this.objectSet.Where(predicate) returns an IEnumerable.  Intellisense shows an IQueryable .Where, but I am not seeing why it is using the IEnumerable one.

Comment: Odd! You can always force it by adding [.AsQueryable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx)

Comment: Ok - got that figured out but still seeing the same behavior.  .Find() is returning an IQueryable<T> using the following:  public IQueryable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate){return this.objectSet.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();}

Comment: OK. Next thing to try is declaring `objectSet` as `ObjectSet<T>` not `IObjectSet<T>`

Comment: You might not need `AsQueryable` if the previous comment works, but anyway, it should go before the Where: `return this.objectSet.AsQueryable().Where( predicate );`

Comment: @Tommy see update 2 on my answer. It explains why `IEnumerable.Where` is getting called instead of `IQueryable.Where`.